# Return plain text from a web service to Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Please see the typescript code below:

```
get(url: string, params?: any): Observable<Response> {
      let options = {  };
        this.setHeaders(options);

      return this.http.get(let url = this.configurationService.serverSettings.webservice + 'api/Product/Get', options)
            .pipe( 
                // retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
                map((res: Response) => {
                    return res;
                }),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }

private setHeaders(options: any, needId?: boolean){
        if (needId && this.securityService) {            
            options["headers"] = new HttpHeaders()
                .append('authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.securityService.GetToken())
                .append('x-requestid', Guid.newGuid());
        }
        else if (this.securityService) {            
            options["headers"] = new HttpHeaders()
                .append('authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.securityService.GetToken());
      }
    }
```

and the web service below, (which is called by the typescript):

```
[Route("Get")]
        public ActionResult<string> SayHello()
        {
            return Json("Hello Bert");
        }
```

The code works as expected i.e. "Hello Bert" is returned to the Typescript.  I want to return text instead of Json.  Therefore I tried changing the web service to:

```
return "Hello Bert"
```

and the Typescript - I added the following line before the last closing bracket of SetHeaders:

```
options["headers"].append('Accept', 'text/plain');
```

Now the web service is called, however the callback in the Typescript is not reached at all.  What is the problem?

Comment: maybe you have a base class in angular or interceptor that tries to parse as JSON everything?

Comment: @Oded BD, it is a default project.  Can you see anything wrong with the code? Thanks.

Comment: no, can you see the response in chrome dev tools, if not it's probably not Angular problem